# Wrong file path while reading from UI

Tags: java, string

I am using windows builder swing UI to get file path from the system using a Jfilechooser.When I select file from Jfile chooser ,file path is shown as-

D:\Tool\BondTest2\xyz.properties

Thats why my java code is not able to read file because as per java syntax file file should be like

D:\\Tool\\BondTest2\\xyz.properties

I write below code for the same but its not working-

```
String filePath = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().toString();
filePath = filePath.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("'\'"), "\\");
System.out.println("change path=" + filePath);
```

But it's not working.Please suggest.

Comment: "as per java syntax file file should be like" - no, that would be the case for *string literals in source code*. If you're just trying to load the file, you don't need that. Also, why are you using regexes at all? Just `filePath.replace("\\", "\\\\")` would be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
String s = "D:\\Tool\\BondTest2\\xyz.properties";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\"));
```

Output:

```
D:\\Tool\\BondTest2\\xyz.properties
```